# docker overlay not seeing UDP messages from particular IP

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, firewall

We have a docker swarm running with overlay.

One of the docker services exposes a UDP endpoint.

I am not seeing UDP traffic from a particular machine in the docker_gwbridge using tshark but I can see UDP traffic coming in from all other machines.

The setup is running on Ubuntu 20 and ufw is inactive.

I checked the iptables and I dont see anything that suggests traffic from that particular IP is blocked.

What else can I look at ?